# How can I make my vertical line fit perfectly inside my div?

Tags: html, css

I have a [banner](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/texxmaa5/1/show/)

[image]

I want to place a vertical line next to my first chapter section.
I've tried add the border-right on my first div.
I've also tried add the border-left on the div next to that, but either one no luck. I can still see the gap in the bottom.

I'm wondering - what is the best to make that line fit perfectly.

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/texxmaa5/1/)

I'm using Bootstrap. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container student-accordion" style="margin-top: 200px;">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1  left">
            <div>Chapter</div>
            <div class="section-num">2</div>
            <div>Practice</div>
            <div>Test</div>
        </span>
        <span class="col-xs-3 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-8  mid">
            <div><b>Practice Test</b></div>
            <div>Algebra 1</div>
            <div>02/09/2015</div>
        </span>
        <span class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1  right">
            <div class="score" >75%</div>
            <div>Score</div>
        </span>
        <span class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1  right">
            <div><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/tf27pu3el/review_white.png" width="40"></div>
            <div>Review</div>
        </span>
        <span class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1  right">
            <div><img src="http://s6.postimg.org/4ag99ja9p/report_white.png" width="40" ></div>
            <div>Report</div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.student-accordion {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
    min-height: 130px;
}

.student-accordion .left {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 15px;
    border-right: solid 2px white;
}

.student-accordion .mid {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 35px;


}

.student-accordion .right {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 35px;

}

.student-accordion .section-num {
    color: white;
    font-size: 39px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
}

.student-accordion .score {
    color: white;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. A link to an external resource does not count as an MCVE. Without this, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.student-accordion` has a `min-height:130px;` and `.student-accordion .left` has a calculated height of 126px giving you a gap on the bottom of 4px.

So the easiest solution is to either remove `min-height: 130px;` from `.student-accordion` or add it to `.student-accordion .left`.

**Edit: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/texxmaa5/2/).**

Comment: @Michael_B - I did use the fiddle. I usually use the built in browser dev tools but on Firefox I also like to use the Firebug plugin. Chrome will list the height in the computed dev tool tab. For Firefox, you will need to to check the "Browser styles" box at the bottom of the computed tab to see all computed styles. Otherwise, you can look at the Box Model tab and add the values.

Comment: `.student-accordian .left` calculated height is actually a sub-pixel value between 125px and 126px. So it will be rendered with either a 4 or 5 pixel gap on the bottom depending on the browser used.

Comment: @Michael_B - I don't think you need to delete your comment as it is relevant to troubleshooting problems like this one. The OP and others may find these comments helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple fix that may work for you. It works in your fiddle demo.

*In the following style rule...*

```
.student-accordion .left {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-right: solid 2px white;
}
```

*... change `padding-top: 10px` to `padding-top: 15px`.*

Answer (score 1):

you could use

1. border-right
2. another div with 1px width
3. img that 1px wide
4. svg line element
5. pesudo element with #2 style
6. box-shadow (least preferable)

Comment: `1- border-right` is clearly doesn't work right now since I have some padding on my main div.

Comment: But thanks for other suggestions, I will try them now.